# ie freezes using mootools request.html ajax

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, mootools, locking, freeze

this is the method:

```
    var ajaxRequest = new Request.HTML({
        method: 'post', 
        url: url + "?dt=" + Date(),
        onFailure: function(item) { alert(item.responseText); },
        onRequest: function(item) { gui.preloader('on'); },
        onSuccess: function(html) {
            gui.preloader('off');
            element.set('text', "");
            element.adopt(html);
            if (element.get('html') == "") alert('No Results... Please try again');
        }            
    }).send(formData);
```

gui.preloader loads a swiff ands sets the visibility accordingly. The problem is that IE locks up in between requests so the animation shows briefly then locks up. Firefox looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Request.HTML also parses the HTML into a DOM object which IE sometimes chokes on, depending on complexity.  As you're emptying out "element" anyway, I'd recommend trying out just `new Request` and `element.set('html', html')`.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try that out. Thanks Eric.